# FFMPEG - Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to save an online input stream from a m3u8 playlist, to a Mp4 file.

Here is my command:

```
usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i '.$stream.' -t 20  \
-vcodec copy -s 640x480 \
-acodec copy  -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc \
-f mp4 '.$filename.'.mp4 > block.txt 2>&1 &
```

And here is my output file:

```
ffmpeg version 2.6.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.3 (GCC) 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic' --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libdc1394 --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, hls,applehttp, from 'playlist.m3u8':
  Duration: N/A, start: 2375.973000, bitrate: N/A
  Program 0 
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 613420
    Stream #0:0: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 613420
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 613420
    Stream #0:2: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp, 53 kb/s
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 613420
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.25.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 613420
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 16000 Hz, mono, 53 kb/s
    Metadata:
      variant_bitrate : 613420
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mp4 @ 0x18e7700] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 168300, current: 168300; changing to 168301. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
frame=   53 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=     163kB time=00:00:02.75 bitrate= 485.9kbits/s    
frame=   79 fps= 74 q=-1.0 size=     294kB time=00:00:04.28 bitrate= 560.7kbits/s    
[mp4 @ 0x18e7700] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 400320, current: 400320; changing to 400321. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x18e7700] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 416970, current: 416970; changing to 416971. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
frame=  131 fps= 81 q=-1.0 size=     466kB time=00:00:07.10 bitrate= 537.4kbits/s    
frame=  150 fps= 67 q=-1.0 size=     506kB time=00:00:08.12 bitrate= 510.2kbits/s    
frame=  163 fps= 59 q=-1.0 size=     549kB time=00:00:08.89 bitrate= 505.4kbits/s    
frame=  177 fps= 54 q=-1.0 size=     621kB time=00:00:09.79 bitrate= 519.4kbits/s    
[mp4 @ 0x18e7700] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 902160, current: 902160; changing to 902161. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
frame=  206 fps= 54 q=-1.0 size=     732kB time=00:00:11.52 bitrate= 520.8kbits/s    
frame=  236 fps= 55 q=-1.0 size=     869kB time=00:00:13.44 bitrate= 529.7kbits/s    
frame=  276 fps= 57 q=-1.0 size=    1036kB time=00:00:15.74 bitrate= 539.0kbits/s    
[mp4 @ 0x18e7700] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 1433880, current: 1433880; changing to 1433881. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
frame=  284 fps= 36 q=-1.0 size=    1079kB time=00:00:16.25 bitrate= 543.7kbits/s    
[mp4 @ 0x18e7700] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 1454490, current: 1454490; changing to 1454491. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
frame=  295 fps= 35 q=-1.0 size=    1129kB time=00:00:16.70 bitrate= 553.9kbits/s    
frame=  317 fps= 35 q=-1.0 size=    1222kB time=00:00:18.04 bitrate= 554.8kbits/s    
[mp4 @ 0x18e7700] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 1696050, current: 1696050; changing to 1696051. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
frame=  347 fps= 36 q=-1.0 size=    1342kB time=00:00:19.39 bitrate= 566.9kbits/s    
frame=  361 fps= 37 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1400kB time=00:00:20.03 bitrate= 572.5kbits/s    
video:1274kB audio:115kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.784608%
```

As you can see, it seems that there are some dropped frame during the recording and I have no idea how to correct this in order to have a clean file at the end.

I believe it's a setting problem maybe? but I can't really pinpoint what's wrong.
I tried to play with the buffer & the framerate but nothing would change.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if it'll help, but have you tried `ffmpeg -re -y ....`?

Comment: @chovy `-re` should *not* be used in this case.  It's only meant to be used when streaming a file to a live output.